# Override constructor to create object from database row

Tags: php, oop, php-7.4

I'm trying to override my constructor to create an object based on a row in my database and I'm unsure of the best way to go about it. My goal is to be able to create the object given the constructor but also have the ability to create the object from a row in my database.

Here is the pseudocode for my given scenerio:

```
class PurchaseOrder
{
  private $id;
  private $title;
  private $amount;

  function __construct($title, $amount)
  {
    $this->title  = $title;
    $this->amount = $amount;
  }

  function constructFromDB($pdo, $id)
  {
    $poValues       = queryPO($pdo, $id);           // fetches from db (psuedocode); 
    $this->title    = $poValues->title;
    $this->amount   = $poValues->amount;
  }
}

// Create new purchase order
$po        = new PurchaseOrder("Purchase Order 1", 100);

// Query purchase order from database
$queriedPO = new PurchaseOrder()->constructFromDB($conn, 1);
```

But as you know, I cannot leave the constructor empty for my object to be initialized. I cannot have it be a static function as I will need to be able to manipulate the object's properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `constructFromDB()` method can be static and return an object:

```
  public static function constructFromDB($pdo, $id)
  {
    $poValues = queryPO($pdo, $id);  // fetches from db (psuedocode); 
    $title    = $poValues->title;
    $amount   = $poValues->amount;
    $class    = __CLASS__;

    return new $class($title, $amount);
  }
```

Then call it statically:

```
$queriedPO = PurchaseOrder::constructFromDB($conn, 1);
```

Comment: If I had a method `insert()` would I be able to do `$queriedPO->insert()`?

Comment: Yes, `$queriedPO` wil be an object of `PurchaseOrder` and will have it's methods.